# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL (with bs4)

Tags: python

I am getting this error:
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'http:/1525/bg.png': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://http:/1525/bg.png?

I don't really care why the error happened, I want to be able to capture any Invalid URL errors, issue a message and proceed with the rest of the code.

Below is my code, where I'm trying to use try/except for that specific error but its not working...

```
# load xkcd page
# save comic image on that page
# follow <previous> comic link
# repeat until last comic is reached

import webbrowser, bs4, os, requests

url = 'http://xkcd.com/1526/'
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)

while not url.endswith('#'): # - last page

    # download the page
    print('Dowloading page %s...' % (url))
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    # find url of the comic image (<div id ="comic"><img src="........" 
    </div
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Could not find any images')
    else:
       comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')

       #download the image
       print('Downloading image... %s' % (comicUrl))
       res = requests.get(comicUrl)
       try:
           res.raise_for_status()
       except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema as err:
           print(err)
           continue

        # save image to folder
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd',
        os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(1000000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

#get <previous> button url
prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')

print('Done')
```

What a my not doing? (I'm on python 3.5)
Thanks allot in advance...

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care about the error (which i see as bad programming), just use a blank except statement that catches all exceptions.

```
#download the image
print('Downloading image... %s' % (comicUrl))
try:
    res = requests.get(comicUrl) # moved inside the try block
    res.raise_for_status()
except:
    continue
```

but on the other hand if your except block isn't catching the exception then it's because the exception actually happens outside your try block, so move `requests.get` into the try block and the exception handling should work (that's if you still need it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked (moving requests inside try loop)

Comment: Hello @AT_1965 don't forget to accept my answer and any SO answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I did reply, with ..."Thanks a lot. It worked (moving requests inside try loop)" yesterday.

Comment: Yes, you did. But simply commenting on an answer doesn't mean it has been accepted. At the top left hand part of my answer there's a grey `tick` mark, click on it and it should turn green, this means that you have accepted the answer as the correct one, the arrows are also used to upvote or downvote answers if you found them helpful or otherwise. If you don't do this, your question will keep on showing up as unanswered and it'll remain in the unanswered queue. you're the only one that can accept an answer.

Comment: Also, looking at your profile i see that you've not accepted any answer, please go through your previous questions and accept the answers that worked for you and solved your problem...welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you have this type of issue occur on use wrong URL.

Solution:

```
import requests

correct_url = False
url = 'Ankit Gandhi' # 'https://gmail.com'
try:
    res = requests.get(url)
    correct_url = True
except:
    print("Please enter a valid URL")
if correct_url:
    """
     Do your operation
    """
    print("Correct URL")
```

Hope this help full.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your try/except block isn't caching the exception is that the error is happening at the line

`res = requests.get(comicUrl)`

Which is above the `try` keyword.

Keeping your code as is, and just moving the `try` block up one line will fix it.